# Anchors not aligning properly on vertical navigation bar

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

**It seems anchor is being fixed to the left side of the vertical navigation, but only for 2nd element++, first element works fine. When I move my cursor to the left most side (empty space) it highlights the link and am able to click it. Still have no idea what is causing this.**

I have made a layout page for a certain part of my website which allows room for a vertical navigation sidebar with a list of navigation points. It remains fixed to the left side. I have had no problem getting the anchors on this side bar working but as soon as I begin styling them (e.g text-align right or font-size change) the anchors to the link remain stuck on the left side or don't work past the first item in the list in the latter.

```
.left-sidebar{

  position:fixed;
  top:auto;
  left:0;
  width:20%;
  height:100%;
  background-color: #3d2c2e;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: auto;
}

.left-sidebar ul{

    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: JosefinSans-Light;
}

.left-sidebar li a{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.left-sidebar li{
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


.left-sidebar li a.active{

    color: white;
}

.left-sidebar li a:hover:not(.active){
    background-color: #555;
    color:white;
}
```

Excuse me if this is a beginner problem, CSS is not my strong point and have tried searching for a solution since last night. Thanks in advance.

Edit HTML:

```
<div class="left-sidebar">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Edit 2:
I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 to create the layout, by copy pasting the main layout into the specific layout and adding in the div above. There are no same css properties within the two layouts.

Edit 3:
I removed all the copied code from layout1 and replaced it with a razor layout expression at the top of the page. Still not working as it should.

Comment: Update the HTML code too.

Comment: @RiotZeastCaptain It's just a simple div atm, please see update.

Comment: Can you not reproduce the error here or in fiddle?

Comment: @John https://jsfiddle.net/461ty6ta it works fine there.

Comment: @choz I've attached a fiddle in the comment above but it's not reproducing the error :\

Answer (score 0):

```
.left-sidebar li a{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
}
```

use `width: 100%;` to the **anchor**(a) tag in the **list**(li) type

Comment: Sorry this is not working either. Please see my second edit for further details.

Comment: ` font-size: 30px;
    text-align: right;` use this css in anchor in list

Comment: Still no luck. Frustrating. The first element works fine, but the rest won't work unless moving cursor all the way to the left.

Comment: What's the exact problem ?

Comment: Within my div I have an unordered list with 3 items in there surrounded by list tags and anchor tags. When I have nothing pertaining to text-align or font-size in my css the first 2 work fine and normal (highlighted & able click link through row not just text), but the last one only highlights when cursor over the text (not the entire row). That is problem one. But I can't have it like that, I need them to be right aligned and font size up to 30px. If I do this, the first item works fine (highlighted & able click link through row not just text) but the other two items don't work at all.